# Is grouped, deferred log statements from same threads possible using logback

Tags: logging, logback

I have read about the Mapped Diagnostic Context, and although useful, the log statements from different threads still appear interspersed in the output.

What I would like is to have all log statements from a thread outout consecutively when that thread is done (and I know what and when "done" is)

For example :

Thread A starts at time T-Astart, performs logging at various points, and is done at T-Adone.

Before A is done, at time T-Bstart (T-Adone < T-Bstart < T-Adone) another thread B starts processing, does the same kind of logging and finishes at T-Bdone.

Now, I would like all logging statements from thread A to appear before the logging statements from Thread B, and not interspersed as the MDC examples I have seen. Is this kind of deferred, grouped logging possible with logback ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this kind of deferred, grouped logging possible with logback ?

It's impossible, so far as I know.

You have one alternative:

- use [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) and MDC to create multiple log files, one for each thread.

Comment: One logfile pr thread won't do for me, I was more thinking in the lines of a stateful encoder